# How to load a js function after a new HTML page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events, onload-event

I wonder if there's a way to do the following:

I have a page on root: "index.html" that has 2 links.  Each link has an `onclick` that directs to "reader/index.html".  The reason for the two links is because I want the links to call different functions on "reader/index.html" immediately after the page is loaded.  Is there a way to do this?

I know how to use `onload` to call a function after a page finished loading, but can't figure out how to use `onload` to call different functions depending on an `onclick` from the previous page.  Totally stumped here.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to pass parameters in the query string:

- First link:
  `reader/index.html?func=function1`
- Second link:
  `reader/index.html?func=function2`

You can read a query string parameter in javascript by using a technique described [here](http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to [pass state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675529/how-to-maintain-state-in-a-web-app-as-http-is-stateless/1675559#1675559) to reader/index.html.

Comment: Any recommendation which pass state is the easiest to understand for a beginner?  I just started learning javascript a few days ago.  Thanks!

Comment: @e1n: Use @kgiannakakis approach. Query string parameters will work.